# equation of a horizontal plane

Tags: c++, vector, 3d

I am having a constructor for a `Plane` using `vector3d` and `position3d`. I want to get horizontal plane at a desired height (say z1). So, I think my plane normal should be (0,0,1). I don't have any other information.

```
Plane::Plane(const position3d &point, const vector3d &normal)
```

I am now really confusing what would be my plane as I am thinking how should I give the `position3d` only with that `Z1`.

quick help soon. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Your position needs to be a point in the plane, no matter which.

Since you said its parallel to XY, you can choose x and y in the position3d arbitrarily.

```
position3d(0,0,z1);
normal(0,0,1);
```

would do the job just fine. Note that you can choose n and m randomly to create `position3d(n,m,z1)`, and still get the same plane.

Answer (score 1):

`point` can be any point on the plane, for instance `(0,0,Z1)`.

Answer (score 1):

A plane can be determined by either 3 points in the space, or a point in the space and a normal (a normalized vector) indicate the direction perpendicular to the plane. In your Plane function, it uses the later definition. So you need to give the point (for example, a point at (0,0,z1)) and the vector (0,0,1) for the Z-axis.